# Declaring cursor in a PL/SQL stored procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

printf('local_time_greeting');

Having some trouble getting a stored procedure to run with SQL Developer. Below is an example patterned exactly like the first few lines, with variable names changed for security reasons.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE redacted ( an_in_variable IN VARCHAR ) AS
    these VARCHAR;
    variables VARCHAR;
    don_apostrophe_t INT;
    matter INT;
BEGIN

DECLARE cursor_giving_me_trouble CURSOR FOR
SELECT something FROM db.table WHERE condition_1 = condition_2;
...
```

In the editor the SELECT word is red-wavy-lined, and when I try to run the code the output returns

```
PLS-00103: Encountered symbol "FOR" when expecting one of the following     := . ( @ % ; not null range default character
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `IS`, not `FOR`. [Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/explicit-cursor-declaration-and-definition.html#GUID-38C5DBA3-9DEC-4AF2-9B5E-7B721D11A77C).

Comment: @AlexPoole Returns the same error, unfortunately

Comment: The order of you sections is reverse. Should be DECLARE ... BEGIN.

Comment: The DECLARE needs its own BEGIN/END which is presumably already there in the `...`; but there shouldn't be a DECLARE before the *existing* BEGIN that is shown - the variable declaration for the main procedure block is OK (apart from the data types...).

Comment: [RTFM](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/index.html)

Comment: Also, Oracle suggest to use VARCHAR2 instead of VARCHAR. Besides, it requires *length*, e.g. `these varchar2(10);`. Therefore, if you *fabricated* code you wrote, it would help if it makes some sense as - obviously - it is not just the cursor that's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `IS` rather than `FOR`, but you have the terms of the definition in the wrong order as well:

```
DECLARE
  CURSOR cursor_giving_me_trouble IS
    SELECT something FROM db.table WHERE condition_1 = condition_2;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=a86eec6e8f788a15c770c32ca91093f7) which still errors because of the illegal object names in your obfuscated code, but not from the syntax; and a [more complete example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=3f9dd2e807bf2ed37a5ea481f4daa85c).

It's also possible you're trying to use the construct:

```
FOR cursor_giving_me_trouble IN (
    SELECT something FROM db.table WHERE condition_1 = condition_2
) LOOP
...
```

rather than a sub-block (a new declare, followed by begin/end) with references only to cursor within that. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=e9902c4909dbc547e8e2c002ed7ecde6).

Answer (score 0):

To get you started:

```
create or replace procedure redacted
    ( an_in_variable in varchar2 )
as
    these varchar2(123);
    variables varchar2(456);
    don_apostrophe_t integer;
    matter integer;
    cursor cursor_giving_me_trouble is
        select 'Welcome to PL/SQL' as whatever from dual where 1=1;
begin
    for r in cursor_giving_me_trouble loop
        dbms_output.put_line(r.whatever);
    end loop;
end;
```

However, you often don't need a separate cursor definition as there is this compact syntax:

```
create or replace procedure redacted
    ( an_in_variable in varchar2 )
as
    these varchar2(123);
    variables varchar2(456);
    don_apostrophe_t integer;
    matter integer;
begin
    for r in (
        select 'Welcome to PL/SQL' as whatever from dual where 1=1
    )
    loop
        dbms_output.put_line(r.whatever);
    end loop;
end;
```